# Read multipage tiff and extract images in golang

Tags: go

How can I split multi page tiff into images in go? image/tiff's DecodeAll return TIFF, which contains image.image. But don't know how to convert each into an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is not much information regarding the package you used in your question, I am going to assume that, you used `github.com/chai2010/tiff` module. It only contains `DecodeAll` method. I used a multipage tiff which was publically available. Then I used the code inside the package [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chai2010/tiff#readme-example). Anyway I'm quoting it here

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/chai2010/tiff"
)

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("Multi_page24bpp.tif")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Decode tiff
    m, errors, err := tiff.DecodeAll(bytes.NewReader(b))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // Encode tiff
    for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(m[i]); j++ {
            newname := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%02d-%02d.tif", filepath.Base("Multi_page24bpp.tif"), i, j)
            if errors[i][j] != nil {
                log.Printf("%s: %v\n", newname, err)
                continue
            }

            var buf bytes.Buffer
            if err = tiff.Encode(&buf, m[i][j], nil); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            if err = ioutil.WriteFile(newname, buf.Bytes(), 0666); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Save %s ok\n", newname)
        }
    }
}
```

It created multiple `tif` images as you asked. I hope that's what you meant

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for. had little trouble to import the package but figured it out.